# How to get username from articles in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Let's say each article is related with a user by holding a user_id value that is a foreign key to the id field in the users table.

And we defined the `user` method inside Article model with `$this->belongsTo('App\User')`, and the `article` method inside User model with `$this->hasMany('App\Article')`.

What is the proper way to get the articles along with the username of the creator, in order to use them in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Article` belongs to a `User`, then like this:

```
$articles = Article::with('user')->paginate();
```

Your Blade template:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <li>{{ $article->title }} by {{ $article->user->username }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks!! I knew it was easier from I was trying : P, I 'll accept when it lets me... cheers!